# Jmagick rounding corners

Tags: imagemagick, rounded-corners, jmagick

I've a question concerning Jmagick, how can I round corners of an image, and does this make sense or would it be better to do this using CSS in HTML ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about JMagick but rounding corners with IM is definitely possible. Check out the "roundRectangle" example here:

[Imagemagick forum](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=8401)

how that command is interfaced by JM, I don't know but it should be easy to find out.